# Calculate combined speed

Tags: vectors, angle

I have a robotic arm that has to move at a defined speed. it has a speed for the X axis, and it has a speed for the Y axis. So if it moves horizontally it uses the X-axis speed, and if it moves Vertically it uses the Y-axis speed. If it moves diagonally it should combine the two speeds. In the image you can see some samples. the vertical and horizontal speeds are given, the angle between the X axis and the diagonal Line is given too.

What I would need to know is how I can calculate the length of the diagonal line (composite speed) with the given informations.

EDIT: the combined speed should follow the ellypse like in the image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use Pythagoras!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that would not give me the correct speed.. my speeds are the arrows shown above. the composite I need follows the ellypse.. with the pythagoras I would end up with a higher speed.

Comment: You should add the information that the speed follows the ellipse in the body of the question.

Comment: @user thank you, added the information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the absolute value of velocity has to follow the ellipse its square can be computed as
$$v^2=\frac {v_x^2v_y^2}{v_x^2\sin^2\theta+v_y^2\cos^2\theta},$$
where $\theta $ is angle with respect to the $x $-axis.

Comment: thank you works great!

Comment: sorry, think I reacted too quickly.. I think I am doing something wrong. with Vx = 10, and Vy = 30, angle = 25°, i'd expect a V = 10,9 but instead I get 15,58. could you please post the calculation with the above sample numbers?

Comment: I computed it in a graphics program.. I add the screenshot to the post

Comment: I am sorry for the error. I have corrected it now.

Comment: thank you! now its working.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have $v_x$ and $v_y$, use the Pythagorean Theorem to get the total velocity $\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am afraid that I have not been clear enough.. the arrows you see in the image are the horizontal and vertical speeds. the speed I need is the diagonal one, and it is shorter than what I would get with the pythagorean Theorem. In the second example, where X and Y spees are the same, also the diagonal speed si the same. With the pythagorean Theorem I would get a higher speed...

Comment: Ahhhh, $v_x$ and $v_y$ determine the size and shape of the ellipse, and you want the velocity at the angle $theta$ on the ellipse. This is different than the normal definition of "combining the two velocities."